# Perform Calculations in MS access

Tags: ms-access, vba

What is the right way to do some calculation in MS access to be stored in the bound table through the user entry form
Should I make use of VBA or simply from access.

Comment: What are the calculations being used for?

Answer (score 0):

You can make simple calculations directly in a textbox for instance. If you set the control source to something like "=A*B", you will see the result of `A * B` in the textbox. However, in VBA you can write more complex functions that you can reuse (even from textboxes "=MyFunction(A,B)").

In VBA Functions you can store intermediate results in variables, perform loops and so on. You can even implement some error handling. This is not possible otherwise.

It makes your application easier to maintain, if you keep the code in a central place in modules, compared to spreading the calculations over dozens of controls in forms and reports.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that you should not store calculations. If you must write a calculation to a bound textbox, you will have to use VBA. If you are using MS Access 2010, you can make use of [calculated columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff945943.aspx).